# How to create two versions of MSIX package (QA\PROD) and deploy on the same machine?

Tags: wpf, azure-devops, publish, msix

What should I change so I can install both QA & Prod versions of app on the same machine?

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

# Build defintion variables to define:
# AgentPool = BUILD2_CD
# Env1 = Dev or  UAT
# Env2 = QA or PROD 
# BuildVersion = 1.0.0.1 , example


trigger:
- none

pool:
  #name: BUILD2
  name: $(AgentPool)
  demands:
  - npm
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
  - vstest
  - DotNetFramework

variables:
  BuildPlatform: 'x64'
  BuildConfiguration: 'release'
  major: 2
  minor: 0
  build: 0
  revision: $[counter('rev', 0)]
  BuildOutputFolder: 'Runtime'
  isDevelop: $[eq(variables['Env1'], 'DEV')] # runtime expression
  CertExportDir: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\$(MsixPackageRootFolderName)'
  CertFilePath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\$(MsixPackageRootFolderName)\PIE21stMortgage.pfx'
  MsixPackageRootFolderName: 'DotnetCoreInstaller_$(BuildVersion)_$(BuildPlatform)_Test'


jobs:
 - job: Phase1 
   displayName: "Client DotnetCore Installer "
   timeoutInMinutes: 50 
   strategy:
     maxParallel: 2
     matrix: 
       ENV_1:
          Multiplier: $(Env1)
       ENV_2:
          Multiplier: $(Env2)
     
   steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'REST API : Update Build Version '
        inputs:
           targetType: filePath
           filePath: ./Automation/RestApi/RestApiVersionCounter.ps1
        continueOnError: true
        env:
         SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)

      - task: PowerShell@1
        displayName: 'PowerShell Script - Update ApplicationRevision '
        inputs:
          scriptType: inlineScript
          inlineScript: |
             $fileVersion =  $Env:BuildVersion.Split(".")
             $last3Numbers = [int]$fileVersion[3].ToString()
     
             $path = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/DotnetCore/DotnetCore.csproj"
             $word = "<ApplicationRevision>.*$"
             $replacement = "<ApplicationRevision>" + $last3Numbers + "</ApplicationRevision>"
             $text = get-content $path 
             $newText = $text -replace $word,$replacement
             $newText > $path
             (Get-Content $path) | Out-File -encoding UTF8 $path
     
      - task: PowerShell@1
        displayName: 'PowerShell Script - Update ApplicationVersion'
        inputs:
          scriptType: inlineScript
          inlineScript: |
             $path = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/DotnetCore/DotnetCore.csproj"
             $word = "<ApplicationVersion>.*$"
             $replacement = "<ApplicationVersion>" + $Env:BuildVersion + "</ApplicationVersion>"
             $text = get-content $path 
             $newText = $text -replace $word,$replacement
             $newText > $path
             (Get-Content $path) | Out-File -encoding UTF8 $path
      
      - task: PowerShell@1
        displayName: 'PowerShell Script - Set BuildOutputFolder variable'
        inputs:
            scriptType: inlineScript
            inlineScript: |
             switch ($env:Multiplier) {
             "PROD" {
                $folderName = "Release"
               }
                "UAT" {
                     $folderName = "UATRelease"
                }
                "DEV" {
                $folderName = "Debug"
                }
                "QA" {
                    $folderName = "QARelease"
                }
                    }
         
             Write-Host "Setting 'BuildOutputFolder' variable to: $folderName" -Verbose
             Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildOutputFolder;]$folderName") -Verbose

  
      - task: FileTransform@1
        displayName: 'File Transform: App.config'
        inputs:
          folderPath: DotnetCoreFolder
          enableXmlTransform: true
          xmlTransformationRules: -transform **\App.$(BuildOutputFolder).config -xml **\App.config
          fileType: xml  

      - powershell: |
         # Update appxmanifest. This must be done before the build.
         [xml]$manifest= get-content ".\DotnetCoreInstaller\Package.appxmanifest"
         # $manifest.Package.Identity.Version = "$(major).$(minor).$(build).$(revision)"    
         $manifest.Package.Identity.Version = "$(BuildVersion)"
         $manifest.Package.Applications.Application.VisualElements.DisplayName = "DotnetCore.$(Multiplier)"  
         $manifest.save("DotnetCoreInstaller/Package.appxmanifest")
        displayName: 'Version Package Manifest'

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          command: 'build'
          projects: '.\DotnetCore\DotnetCore.csproj'

      - task: CopyFiles@1
        displayName: 'Copy PIE21stMortgage.pfx File to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: D:\versions\CERT
          Contents: PIE21stMortgage.pfx
          TargetFolder: $(CertExportDir)

      - task: MSBuild@1
        inputs:
          solution: DotnetCoreInstaller/DotnetCoreInstaller.wapproj
          platform: $(buildPlatform)
          configuration: $(buildConfiguration)
          msbuildArguments: '/p:OutputPath=NonPackagedApp
          /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=SideLoadOnly  
          /p:AppxBundle=Never 
          /p:GenerateAppInstallerFile=True 
          /p:AppInstallerUri=\\shares\Intranet\$(Multiplier)\DotnetCore 
          /p:AppInstallerCheckForUpdateFrequency=OnApplicationRun 
          /p:AppInstallerUpdateFrequency=1
          /p:AppxPackageOutput=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\DesktopApp.msix 
          /p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=false
          /p:PublishAssemblyName=$(Multiplier)
          /p:ProductName=$(Multiplier)'
        displayName: 'Package the App'

      - script: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x64\signtool"
        sign /fd SHA256 /f $(CertExportDir)/$(CertName) /p "$(CertPassword)" $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\DesktopApp.msix'
        displayName: 'Sign MSIX Package'

      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: 'Publish Artifact: MSIX Package'
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
          ArtifactName: ClientDotnetCoreInstaller$(Multiplier)

       
      - task: CopyFiles@1
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          Contents: '**'
          TargetFolder: '\\shares\Intranet\$(Multiplier)\DotnetCore'
          OverWrite: true
  
      - task: DeleteFiles@1
        displayName: 'Delete PIE21stMortgage.pfx'
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '\\21stmortgage\shares\Intranet\$(Multiplier)\DotnetCore\AppxPackages\$(MsixPackageRootFolderName)'
          Contents: 'PIE21stMortgage.pfx'    


      - task: DeleteFiles@1
        displayName: 'Delete files from $(Build.SourcesDirectory) '
        condition: always()
        continueOnError: True
        enabled: False
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
          Contents: '\*'
```

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out  below answer? How did it go?

Comment: Hi Levi. I did but that is not what I was asking for. I am not asking about application revisions but the application itself. I will post my solution shortly. Thanks for checking in.

Answer (score 0):

In above yaml pipeline. There are two powershell tasks `PowerShell Script - Update ApplicationRevision` to update the ApplicationRevision. The second powershell task will override the first one. You can use [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for above powershell tasks, so that only one of them will run in each strategy. See below:

```
- task: PowerShell@1
        displayName: 'PowerShell Script - Update ApplicationRevision '
        condtion: eq(variables['Multiplier'],'QA')
        inputs:
          scriptType: inlineScript
          inlineScript: |
             $fileVersion =  $Env:BuildVersion.Split(".")
             $last3Numbers = [int]$fileVersion[3].ToString()
              ...
        
     
- task: PowerShell@1
        displayName: 'PowerShell Script - Update ApplicationVersion'
        condtion: eq(variables['Multiplier'],'Prod')
        inputs:
          scriptType: inlineScript
          inlineScript: |
             $path = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/DotnetCore/DotnetCore.csproj"
             $word = "<ApplicationVersion>.*$"
           ....
```

Add **condtions** to powershell task to make them run in their strategy.